# Ruby on Rails how to get last query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm having trouble trying to figure out when I reached the end of my query. So what I want to do is list all the records in my database that begin with the letter A which I got however I want to output a message if the query turns out blank. When I try I get a bunch of my custom messages even the query didn't turn out blank. Is there any way to tell if I've reached EOF in ruby on rails?

Sample

```
    <div id = "content-A">
                <p>A</p>
                <% @animes.each do |anime| %>
                    <% if anime.aname.starts_with?('A') %>
                        <%= link_to anime.aname, {:action => 'list'} %>
                    <% else %>
                        <p>No anime listed in this Category :( </p>
                    <%end%>
                <%end %>
            </div>
```

Comment: What is your query that generates `@animes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want sth like:

```
<% animes_group = @animes.group_by {|anime| anime.aname.to_s[0].upcase}
  ('A'..'Z').each do |letter| %>
  <div id="content-<%= letter %>">
  <p><%= letter %></p>
  <% if animes = animes_group[letter] %>
    <% animes.each do |anime| %>
      <%= link_to anime.aname, {:action => 'list'} %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <p>No anime listed in this Category :( </p>
  <%end%>
<% end %>
```

You should consider moving some of the logic to the controller here, however what is to be moved depends on many factors like whether @animes are being used anywhere else etc.

Comment: @mav191 - This should display all the letters already, unless you do some tricky business with `@animes`.

Comment: It's not displaying the one's that turn up empty? If it turns up empty it should still display the letter and the error output

Comment: @mav191 - AH, true to that. I'll update an answer in a second.

Comment: what the animes variable do? It doesn't seem to be initialized

Comment: @mav191 - it is initialized in if statement

Comment: Also keep getting this error : _undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass_

Comment: I have updated answer some time ago to fix this error. The only other case of this error is if you have anime without `aname`. WIll handle this case as well.

Comment: All right man it works flawlessly...Thanks so much for the help!!